# Scan unstructured JSON BYTEA into map[string]string

Tags: sql, json, go

This seems like a common problem and may be posted somewhere already, but I can't find any threads talking about it, so here is the problem:

I have a Postgres table storeing a column of type `BYTEA`.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id         VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
  json_data  BYTEA
)
```

The column `json_data` is really just JSON stored as `BYTEA` (It's not ideal I know). It is unstructured, but guaranteed to be of `string -> string` JSON.

When I query this table, I need to scan the query `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = $1` into the following struct:

```
type JSONData map[string]string

type Foo struct {
  ID    string   `db:"id"`
  Data  JSONData `db:"json_data"`
}
```

I'm using [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx)'s [`Get`](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/blob/master/sqlx.go#L327) method. When I execute a query I'm getting the error message `sql: Scan error on column index 1, name "json_data": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *foo.JSONData`.

Obviously, the scanner is having trouble scanning the JSON `BYTEA` into a map. I can implement my own scanner and call my custom scanner on the `json_data` column, but I'm wondering if there are better ways to do this. Could my `JSONData` type implement an existing interface to do this automatically?

Comment: what happens if you set JSONData as map[string]interface{} ?

Comment: @jakob Getting the same error.

Comment: Implement the [Scanner](https://godoc.org/database/sql#Scanner) interface on `*JSONData`.   Call `json.Unmarshal` in that implementation.

Comment: Ah that worked. Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you storing the JSON value in a column defined as `jsonb`?  Storing it into a `bytea` is a really bad idea. You will probably have substantially less problems using that if you use the proper data type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know, it's a long story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @iLoveReflection, implementing the [Scanner](https://godoc.org/database/sql#Scanner) interface on `*JSONData` worked. Here is the actual implementation:

```golang
func (j *JSONData) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    b, ok := src.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("invalid data type")
    }

    return json.Unmarshal(b, j)
}
```